# Suppose $(X_{n})_{n}$ is series of i.i.d. random variables and $E(X_{1})=2$. Compute $\lim_{n\to\infty} (n \ln (\varphi_{X_{1}}(\frac{2}{n})))$

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, random-variables, characteristic-functions, law-of-large-numbers

Let's define $S_{n}=\sum_{k=1}^{n} X_{k}$. According to strong law of large numbers we have $\frac{S_{n}}{n} \rightarrow E(X_{1})=2$ a.s. It follows from that $\frac{S_{n}}{n} \rightarrow 2$ in distribution.

According to the continuity theorem $\lim_{n\to\infty} \varphi_{\frac{S_{n}}{n}}(t)=\varphi_{\delta(2)}(t), \forall t\in \mathbb{R}.$

Especially for $t=2$ we have:$$ \varphi_{\frac{S_{n}}{n}}(2)=\varphi_{S_{n}}(\frac{2}{n})=\varphi_{\sum_{k=1}^{n} X_{k}}(\frac{2}{n})=\prod_{k=1}^{n} \varphi_{X_{k}}(\frac{2}{n})=(\varphi_{X_{1}}(\frac{2}{n}))^{n}$$ and we can conclude $\lim_{n\to\infty} \varphi_{\frac{S_{n}}{n}}(2)=\lim_{n\to\infty}(\varphi_{X_{1}}(\frac{2}{n}))^{n}.$ Function $x\rightarrow \ln(x)$ is continuous so limit and function can commute. $$\ln(\lim_{n\to\infty}\varphi_{\frac{S_{n}}{n}}(2))=\ln(\lim_{n\to\infty}(\varphi_{X_{1}}(\frac{2}{n}))^{n})=\lim_{n\to\infty}\ln(\varphi_{X_{1}}(\frac{2}{n})^{n})=\lim_{n\to\infty}(n\ln(\varphi_{X_{1}}(\frac{2}{n})).$$ On the other hand, $$\ln(\lim_{n\to\infty}\varphi_{\frac{S_{n}}{n}}(2))=\ln(\varphi_{\delta(2)}(2))=\ln(e^{4\cdot i})=4\cdot i.$$ Final solution is $\lim_{n\to\infty}(n\ln(\varphi_{X_{1}}(\frac{2}{n})))=4\cdot i$.
I hope that solution is correct. Every comment is welcome, thanks in advance.

Comment: $\mu=E[X_1]$, $S_n/n\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}\mu$ a.s. and in $L_1$. This $S_n/n$ converges in law to $\delta_\mu$; hence
$$E[\exp(itS_n/n)]=\big(\phi(t/n)\big)^n\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}e^{it\mu}$$ If you take $\log$, you may have to choose a branch of log that contains $e^{it\mu}$.

Comment: .. different branches will give you $it\mu +2\pi in$